# How make an inside element ignore the style

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

```
<ul id="login">
    <li><a href="#">User></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout></a></li>
</ul>
```

I did make my menu and sub menu work ok. But the last item came from a Partial view doesnt show because this line

```
/* hide the second level menu */
    .menu ul {
           display: none;
```

I try putting using `:not` selector, but then show in a wrong format and first sub menu stop working.

```
.menu ul:not(#login)
```

On this sample, all four `<LI>` element should have same format and first one display the submenu.

Also try creating a different class for the second `UL` and ignore me.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.menu li a {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 11px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu li a:hover, .menu li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #9CA3DA;
}

/* hide the second level menu */
.menu ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

/* display second level menu on hover */
.menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  color: #797979;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover > a {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-left: 3px solid #9CA3DA;
  color: #797979;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>HOME</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>ABOUT</a></li>
    <li>            
        <ul id="login">
            <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Dont know if is because the html engine, but right now doesnt allow me select the items inside the sub menu. The sub menu disapear when try to go below `HOME` if move the mouse very slow

Comment: Why don't you use `.menu .sub-menu` instead of `.menu ul`? Anyway it's hard to get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Pangloss I want see four items `HOME ABOUT USER LOGOUT` right now the last two doesnt show. If I use `:not` selector will show, but sub-menu stop working

Comment: Is the HTML code generated from the back-end, are you able to edit it?

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, I have access to all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you didn't put `User`and `Logout` at the same level of `Home` and `About` like that:

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>HOME</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>ABOUT</a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

It should work !

**EDIT**

With the following modification of css, your menu should work.

```
.menu ul.sub-menu li a { ... }
.menu ul.sub-menu li a:hover, .menu ul.sub-menu li:hover > a { ... }
#login {padding: 0; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/BzKXrR)

Comment: Because that was the result from a Partial View

Comment: Ok, so you can add `sub-menu` class in your css instead of `not{#login}`. Hope this pen works for you: http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/BzKXrR

Comment: yes, this seem to work ok. Any idea why if you move the mouse slow beetween the menu and sub menu the sub menu close?

Comment: I've updated the pen. Just remove the gap between the `li` and its `sub-menu` by setting 40px (not 43px) to the sub-menu

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>HOME</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>ABOUT</a></li>
    <li id="user"><a href="#">USER</a></li>
    <li id="logout"><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

You've placed the ABOUT link in a list item by itself.
Here's the proper HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>HOME</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>ABOUT</a>
        <ul id="login">
            <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You didnt understand. `User` and `Logout` should be on the nav bar not submenu for `About`. So I want 4 item on the nav bar. One will have submenu. In this case the `HOME`

Comment: So you want 4 inline items, such as:

HOME    ABOUT    USER    LOGOUT

You'll still have the sub-menu items under HOME.
Is this what you want?

Comment: Correct, right now the last two doesnt show. When i try using `:not` selector show but then sub-menu items stop working

Comment: Is working great. Can you explain this line `.menu ul.sub-menu li a:hover, .menu ul.sub-menu li:hover > a ` I know this code generate the left color bar to indicate hover item. But why you need two selectors?